# Undefined variable outside subscribe function

Tags: angular

I'm trying to extract an element of an array but seems to be undefined.

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(
            (params : Params) =>{
                this.id = params.id;
            });
            this.store.select('users').subscribe( data => {
                this.users = data.users;
            });
            this.userService.getUserDetails(this.users[this.id].userId).subscribe( 
                user => {
                   this.userToEdit = user.Data;
                   console.log(this.userToEdit); <- this is showing the object
                })
        console.log(this.userToEdit); <- undefined
        this.initForm();
    }
```

How should i do to have the value be also set at that moment of time outside the subscribe function.

Comment: This is because of async call for getUserDetails method. Until an, unless API completes its execution, you will not able to get value for `this.userToEdit`

Comment: These are anync tasks, since inner subscriptions belong to others, you should use `switchMap()`